# Force data to stay in cache

Tags: postgresql, caching

I have a part of a large table in PostgreSQL 12 that I would like to be cached at all times. The queries are such that the same rows would (almost) never be read twice, so I can't rely on the automatic caching. I'm reading up on pg_prewarm which seems suitable for loading the cache, but I don't find anything about preventing it being overwritten over time. Any hints? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there is no documented feature in PostgreSQL to lock pages for a specific object in the database cache.

Comment: Ok, nothing to do about it then :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That is true. The only way you can make sure that the table stays cached is to have `shared_buffers` big enough to contain the whole database.

But in practice that is no big problem: if a block doesn't get used regularly, it can drop out of the cache, so you have to read it in again when it gets used. But a single block contains many rows, so it only drops out if none of these rows are needed.

Comment: The table is unfortunately clustered such that a given query will read ~10 kb of continuous data, so it will just use 1-2 blocks.

Comment: Then I don't see the problem. Reading 10kB of continuous data will read just a few blocks. That should only take a few miliseconds to read from disk.

Comment: Sorry, I managed to confused myself :) Any given query will actually read ~1500 blocks.